# call vector::size() on vector stored in boost::any

Tags: c++, boost

I have value stored in `boost::any` and I would like to have function which would return number of elements if `boost::any` holds `std::vector`.

Here is example of use:

```
int a = 42;
vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
vector<int> w;

boost::any aa = a;
boost::any av = v;
boost::any aw = w;

// I would like to have this function `count`
count( aa ) // return 1
count( av ) // return 4
count( aw ) // return 0

// I can do following. But I do not like the template argument.
count<int>( aa ) // return 1
count<int>( av ) // return 4
count<int>( aw ) // return 0
count<float>( aa ) // error
```

The problem is that I cant simply cast to `vector<T>` without specifying `T`. Is there a way around it?

Comment: You want to write a helper function that uses type traits to figure out what type `any` is holding and `count` appropriately.

Comment: @PaulEvans: How would you plan to do that? You can't enumerate a finite set. There are infinitely many vector types.

Comment: The core of the problem is that `std::vector<X>::size()` is quite unrelated to `std::vector<Y>::size`. There's no way to know if vector is specialized for some types. (We know in fact it's specialized for `bool` but it may be specialized in less obvious ways for other types, e.g. POD types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to use an intermediate container:

```
class vector_holder_base {
public:
    virtual std::size_t size() = 0;
}

template <class T, class... Others>
class vector_holder : public vector_holder_base {
public:
    vector_holder(const std::vector<T, Others...>& val) {...}
    vector_holder(std::vector<T, Others...>&& val) {...}
    vector_holder& operator=(const std::vector<T, Others...>& val) {...}
    vector_holder& operator=(std::vector<T, Others...>&& val) {...}

    std::size_t size() override {
        return values.size();
    }
private:
    std::vector<T, Others...> values;
}
```

Then all you have to do is:

```
boost::any aa = vector_holder<int>(a);
std::size_t count = boost::any_cast<vector_holder_base>(aa).size();
```

As you can see with this trick you don't need to know the vector template type when you retrieve the size.

Yet, you need to think about multiple copies of your vector (when you pass it to a `vector_holder`, and then when the `vector_holder` is copied into a `boost::any` (think about move semantics).

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<float>` are unrelated types at runtime.

`boost::any` type erases copying and extraction to its own type (exactly), and no more.

If you want to take unrelated (runtime) types and type erase additional properties, you should examine [`boost.TypeErasure`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html), or do such erasure yourself.

Alternatively, an augmented `any` (with type erased `size`) could work.  Assuming C++11 support:

```
struct sized_any;
typedef std::size_t(sizer_t*)(sized_any const*)>;
template<class ValueType>
struct make_sizer {
  sizer_t operator()() const {
    return [](sized_any const*){return 1;}
  }
};
template<class ValueType, class... Whatever>
struct make_sizer< std::vector<ValueType, Whatever...> > {
  sizer_t operator()() const {
    return [](sized_any const* n){
      // convert n to a const std::vector<ValueType, Whatever...>*
      // invoke .size()
    }
  }
};
struct sized_any : private boost::any {
  sized_any( sized_any const& o ) = default;
  sized_any( sized_any && o ) = default;
  sized_any():boost::any(), size([](sized_any const*){return 0;}) {}
  sized_any & operator=(const sized_any &) = default;
  sized_any & operator=(sized_any &&) = default;
  template<typename ValueType> sized_any(const ValueType &v):boost::any(v), sizer(make_sizer<ValueType>{}())
  {}
  template<typename ValueType> sized_any(ValueType &&v):boost::any(std::move(v)), sizer(make_sizer<ValueType>{}())
  {}
  template<typename ValueType> sized_any & operator=(const ValueType & v){
    this->boost::any::operator=(v);
    sizer=make_sizer<ValueType>{}();
    return *this;
  }
  template<typename ValueType> sized_any & operator=(ValueType && v) {
    this->boost::any::operator=(std::move(v));
    sizer=make_sizer<ValueType>{}();
    return *this;
  }

  ~sized_any() = default;

  // modifiers
  sized_any & swap(sized_any & o) { this->boost::any::swap(o); std::swap( sizer, o.sizer ); }
  std::size_t size() const { return sizer(this); }
private:
  sizer_t sizer;
};
```

the private inheritance of `boost::any` is to block `boost::any::swap` from being called directly, or other functions that can change what type is stored in the `boost::any`.  You have to reimplement/forward functions that operate on `boost::any` to operate on `sized_any`.

The basic design is simple.  We maintain a `boost::any`, and whenever its type changes, we build a new function pointer that can extract the proper size from it.  The sizer takes a pointer to our `sized_any` to make our copy/assignment operators easier, plus that is all the state it needs (so we don't need to store any state in the function pointer).

The above is not a complete implementation, but a sketch.

The extra state (the function pointer) has to be maintained independently, so stateless modification of the `any` isn't possible.